# combining open(Filename, {delayed_write, Size, Delay}) with index

Tags: file-io, erlang

How can I combine a open(Filename, {delayed_write, Size, Delay}) with an index on where to write this data to?

I want to wait until I receive a certain amount of data and then write it to a position in the file.

Also is {read_ahead, Size} the opposite of {delayed_write, Size, Delay}? I would like to read a certain amount of data to send it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read_ahead is kind of the opposite of delayed_write in the sense that reading is the opposite of writing.

If you want to read and send bigger chunks of memory you don't need read_ahead, just read big chunks and send them (not many os calls to save here).

From the [file:open/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2) manpage on read_ahead:

> If  read/2  calls  are for sizes not significantly less than, or even greater  than  Size
>                       bytes, no performance gain can be expected.

You don't need to specify and index when opening.  Just use [pwrite/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pwrite-3) or a combination of [position/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#position-2) and [write/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#write-2).

But writing in different positions of the file might just reduce the gain of `delayed_write` since (also manpage of [file:open/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2)):

> The  buffered
>                       data  is  also flushed before some other file
>                       operation than write/2 is executed.

If you have chunks of data for several positions collect them in a list of `{Location, Bytes}` and from time to time write them with [file:pwrite/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pwrite-2) all in one go.  This can map to very efficient `writev(2)` system call that writes several chunks in one go.

Comment: So I would just pass it the entire list and it will write or do I have to iterate through the list writing each element?

Comment: Also, would I need to have a process running and waiting to receive these, and loop with the list data?If so, how is the list emptied after I write to the disk?thanks

Comment: You pass the list to pwrite/2 and it writes everything itself and with good performance.  The chunks to write would indeed be collected by your receiving loop.  But let me ask another question before going into details: are you sure you have a performance bottleneck writing to the disk?  Can you give a bit more details what you want to do (e.g. average chunk size of the data, speed with which it arrives etc.)  Also are you aware of the two rules of optimization?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I will be downloading and uploading, it will be using the bittorrent protocol. I am not aware of the 2 rules.

Comment: 1. Don't optimize before you measure. 2. RULE #1 IS IMPORTANT!!! If you go the pwrite/2 route, etorrent could use a patch for that. I just use a position-change/write combo.

Comment: While I agree 100% percent with IGCA's rules I had something different in mind: Rules of optmization (I think attributed to Ed Yourdon): Rule 1: Don't do it!  Rule 2 (FOR EXPERTS ONLY!): Don't do it yet!

Comment: To go back to the question if it is worth it to use pwrite/2: If the bittorrent usually runs over a internet connection, the filesystem bandwith of a normal harddisk should not be a bottleneck.  I don't know the characteristics of bittorrent: the question is how small the chunks are that you get from the network.  OTOH the filesystem on decent operating systems is doing its own block buffering.  So it boils down to reduce system call frequency.  But generally you also have to read each chunk from the network (with syscall).  Summary: use pwrite/3 and forget about buffering ...

Comment: ... and if performance sucks: Measure and then fix the real reason for your performance problems.

Comment: Thanks. so I should skip the list idea and rather just receive and write to the disk, I never really asked about optimization :P So to clarify. Open the file on the process creation and wait to receive. What should be received if its not {location, bytes}?

Comment: @alJaree: read_ahead and delayed_write are optimization options.  I can't tell what you receive, don't know bittorrent protocol details.  But at some point you will probably somehow get some data and information where to put it and this you will use with pwrite/3